# TDD in theory only

Tags: testing, development-process

A little over a year ago I was fortunate enough to be able to take a 9 month break from work.  I decided that in that time time I would hone my C# skills.  I started working on a bunch of projects and forced myself to follow TDD.

It was a fairly enlightening process.

It was tough at first, but over time I learned how to write more testable code (which, as it turns out, tends to be more SOLID code) and in the process I also sharpened my OO design skill.

Now I'm back in the workforce and I'm noticing something odd.

**I prefer not to follow TDD.**

I find TDD slows me down and actually makes it harder to design a clean application.

Instead, I've adopted a slightly (massively) different approach:

1. Pick a vertical slice of work
2. Develop a functioning prototype
3. Refactor until everything is nice and tidy
4. Sit back an appreciate the beautifully SOLID and testable code I've written.

You may have noticed that step 1 wasn't "define the public surface of my test target" and step 2 wasn't "test the bejesus out of said public surface."  You may have also noticed that none of the steps involve testing.  I'm writing testable code, but I'm not testing it... just yet.

Now, I'd like to make it clear that I'm not actually foregoing any kind of testing.  The code I'm writing *works*.  It works because I'm testing it manually.

I'd also like to make it clear that I'm not foregoing all automated testing either.  This is where my process is different.  And this is why I'm asking this question.

### TDD in theory.  Not in practice.

My process has evolved a bit and I've struck a balance between TDD and no tests that I find very productive and also reasonably safe.  It goes as follows:

1. Implement a working vertical slice of work with testing in mind, but don't write any tests.
2. If down the road (eg, a month later) that slice needs modification

   1. Write Unit Tests, Integration Tests, Behaviour Tests, etc that guarantee the slice of work is correct
   2. Modify the code
3. If that slice doesn't need modification,

   1. Do nothing

By simply shifting the burden of writing tests from before *writing* the code to before *modifying* the code I've been able to produce much more working code.  And, when I do get around to writing tests I write far fewer of them but cover nearly as much ground (higher ROI).

I like this process, but I'm concerned it might not scale well.  Its success hinges on developers being diligent about writing tests before they change things.  And that seems like a pretty big risk.  But, TDD has the very same risk.

So, am I going to [BT]DD hell, or is this a common form of pragmatic coding and testing?

**I'd like to keep working this way.  What can I do to make this process work in the long term?**

Note:

I am the sole developer on my projects and I am responsible for everything:  Requirements gathering, design, architecture, testing, deployment, etc.  I suspect this is why my process is working.

Comment: Looks like spike and stabilize with out always doing the stabilizing if `If that slice doesn't need modification`.  http://lizkeogh.com/2012/06/24/beyond-test-driven-development/

Comment: The does indeed sound *a lot* like what I'm doing.  I didn't know it had a name.  Thanks :)

Comment: Unit tests are most useful when the code is in flux. That does include when it's being modified, but it also includes when it's first being written. Why do you prefer automated tests in the former case and manual in the latter?

Comment: You're discovering something about TDD that I've long suspected, that the *test first* mantra is an exceptionally good *learning tool,* but it is *not design,* it merely encourages good design.  In the end, what you want is testable code and unit tests that provide good code coverage and mirror the software's requirements; as you are finding out, you can get that without writing the tests *first,* if you practice sensible design principles.

Comment: @BenAaronson I assume it's because I'm not working off of well define requirements or acceptance criteria.  I'm constantly prototyping.

Comment: Yep, and writing tests first essentially doubles your prototyping work.

Comment: What does "slightly (massively)" mean?

Comment: it means I was lying about it being "slightly."

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to start a debate about a process you're applying. It is by its nature unique and likely very subjective.

Comment: yes, I realized that when I was sketching this question out.  I hope to have time this weekend to reword a few things and fix that.

Comment: I do similar, and I dislike the 'unit test frameworks' quite a lot for their whole approach. However, I do test the few complicated routines that obviously require them, but the majority of my after-modification testing is via integration tests, part manual, part automated. I should automate more of them, but that costs more up-front than the business is prepared to pay.

Comment: I don't mind unit test frameworks.  I just don't like writing tests while my code is still in flux.  I think the solution to my concerns is a bit of diligence.  If I make a point of dedicating a little time each sprint to writing tests for unchanged code at least I won't be leaving an undocumented project to the next developer.

Comment: "And, when I do get around to writing tests I write far fewer of them but cover nearly as much ground (higher ROI)" When you say write far fewer of them, do you just mean because you're only testing code you're changing, or are you saying that you're somehow covering the same (tested) piece of code with fewer tests than if you'd used TDD?

Comment: I tend to write higher level tests (integration or behaviour) which are less granular, but cover much of the same ground as a suite of unit tests.  Also, because I only write my tests once the feature is stable (and usually approved by the end user) I hardly ever find myself deleting tests when things need to be completely overhauled.  Keep in mind I haven't actually been gathering hard data on this.  This is just how it feels when I look back at my last year of work.

Comment: I too missed the line that Alex Feinman just helpfully highlighted. It seems to be a completely different question from the one asked in the line before- I don't think they both fit together in a single question.

Comment: I just cannot accept that both written code and refactoring as you present it will result in working code.
**It works because I'm testing it manually.** And this DOESN'T slow you down? I don't trust you if you say it doesn't.

Comment: "_I am the sole developer on my projects..._" I too am the sole developer on my projects after taking over from the last sole developer on the projects, and man I would have appreciated it if **that** sole developer had written some tests!

Comment: Just a follow up on this.  It's been a while, but I do believe I spent time writing a full suite of integration/behaviour tests before leaving that project.  I'm sorry your predecessor didn't :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the process work in the long term I would write the tests when the code is being written.

Which may seem to contradict your approach.  However you've posed the question so I'll give you my take:

You don't have to write the tests before the code.  forget that purity.  However you want to write the tests **around** that time.
Once you have got the code working, you've tweaked it a bit, got some bugs out (we're talking about a timescale of hours here), you are then at a point of maximum knowledge about what the code is doing.  This is a great time to write tests that capture your knowledge.

Leaving this until later means the knowledge will (naturally) diminish over time.

It also means that should you ever leave and should anyone else take over you will not have the immediate technical debt of not having documented (through tests) what does what.

Most of all, "some day" may not come.  You may either get hit by a bus or you might board the bus for new adventures.

Finally, manual testing doesn't scale and frequently doesn't cover all the devices used by the end user.

Comment: I think I like your suggested approach and I'll probably apply it when I can.  My work is very fragmented though, so "a timescale of hours" is not always possible.  Unfortunately I'm on support too so I often get pulled off my work to help fight fires :)  But, that's life.

Comment: The issue though is that tomorrow never comes, there's always the next feature.  And what are you going to chose to do; write the next feature, or write the tests for the thing you just "finished?"

Answer (score 9):

Although TDD is tough to implement 100% there is a flaw in your approach

1. Implement a working vertical slice of work

   1.1 1 year passes....

   1.2 A new dev starts work on the project
2. If that slice needs modification

   2.3 Parse 'Clean Coding' style method names and parameters 'GetUnicorn(colourOfUnicorn)'

   2.4 Read xml comments 'Gets A gold unicorn (for riding)(obvs)'

   2.5 Hunt down the original dev

   2.6 Hope they remember what the code is supposed to do

   2.7 Get them to explain it all
3. Write Unit Tests, Integration Tests, Behaviour Tests, etc that
   **hopefully** guarantee the slice of work is correct
4. Modify the code

I think you are correct to identify that unit tests really show their value when modifications are required.

Comment: Hey, I write self documenting code!  My classes have one responsibility and are, therefore, easy to understand.  Nobody will need to hunt me down :)

Comment: @MetaFight and if they do, you'll be easy to spot on top of the solid gold living unicorn!

Comment: I call him Goldicorn.

Comment: On a more serious note, yes, you have a point.  I've considered logging "testing debt" stories so that I can pay some back when my work load is lighter.

Comment: If the code is written well, but has a bug, it will probably be fairly easy to understand what the original developer _meant_ to accomplish by reading the code, and the new dev can add the necessary tests. The only problem is that most developers think they are writing good code. "Good" depends heavily on your perspective and experience as a programmer. So, there's a tension in this that has to be managed.

Comment: i dont know, I seem to spend half my time investigating bugs which turn out to be intended functionality

Comment: @Ewan this would seem to hint that your requirements gathering and analysis is off.  That, or the dev implementing the *correct* requirement got confused and QA missed it.  Either way, using Acceptance Criteria will help here.

Comment: Or the user doesnt understand a feature reports it as a bug, QA confirm the behaviour and pass it up for fixing

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I've been over the steps again and, I know you're going to be upset, but no-one mention the unicorn had to be _living_, so if you can just sign off that the unicorn is as requested we'll take this feedback on board and look to fix it in the next release...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with both Daniel Hollinrake and Ewan, that the first key point why your test-only-if-modify works well so far is:

```
I am the sole developer on my projects and I am responsible for everything
```

and that a likely second key point is:

```
you're producing nice clean code
```

I do not think TDD brings a huge productivity boost for sole programmers, and it may not hugely improve the quality of your code if you are already writing good clean code.

However, TDD will surely improve the quality of the code of poor / inexperienced / obsolete programmers, especially when the time comes to modify the code without breaking anything else. And even more so if the person modifying the code is not the same person that wrote the code originally or several months have passed in between.

In other words, I think TDD is both good practice to improve the quality of your code (as you acknowledge yourself) but also (and more important) a sort of hedge when you are working with average or mediocre programmers (say, from a different department or a different company) which is a far more common situation than working solo.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that there may be only 1 programmer but the code base will often grow over time and what worked (for testing) when it was small doesn't keep working as it gets larger.

Answer (score 3):

For me the key thing appears to be this:

> I am the sole developer on my projects and I am responsible for
>   everything: Requirements gathering, design, architecture, testing,
>   deployment, etc. I suspect this is why my process is working.

This works for you and you're producing nice clean code (I assume!). The only thing I would say you need to do is create a test harness so as other developers can come in and be confident in making changes. Also the test harness ensures consistency in the code's behaviour.

I think your approach is is similar to mine. I am usually the sole developer on my projects. I've found that an appreciation of TDD has enabled me to write smaller functions and cleaner code but I add tests whilst writing the code as a test harness. That way as the code evolves and functionality changes I can be reasonably confident in making changes.

A secondary reason for writing tests is that I feel they are a form of documentation. They can explain my reasonings behind why a function was created. But here, I'm thinking more about Behaviour Driven Development.

Comment: I'd say test suite would come in at 4th place for passing on to other devs - requirements doc, architecture diagrams and design docs would be much more important to communicate matters than a bunch of unit tests.

Comment: It's a fair point, but sadly in my experience, on nearly every project I've worked on the documentation, when it exists, is either out of date or incomplete.

Comment: Same here, which is why devs should realise the importance of documenting things and not writing more code in the form of tests! Maybe we need tools to allow for better documentation generation (ie that isn't just the pretty formatting of method signatures) from code comments and requirement tickets.

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit in response to your comments. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried to upvote this only to realise I had already upvoted it :)

Comment: @gbjbaanb If I can help it, I like to avoid writing requirements docs, architecture diagrams, and design docs.  This is because they tend to go stale very fast.  In my case I'm pretty lucky as I manage many small applications with very few responsibilities.  This makes requirements and architecture documentation a bit overkill.  And the projects are small enough that the overall design is clear.  What I *am* documenting, however, is how the systems interact, how to deploy them, and how to monitor their health.

Comment: @MetaFight so you dislike writing architecture and design docs, yet you admit you are writing architecture and design docs. I'm not sure what you're saying, unless its that you have a prejudice against some traditional documentation descriptions.

Comment: Sorry, where did I say I write architecture and design docs?  I guess you could argue that my documentation of how my systems interact is a kind of inter-system architecture document... but this stuff is so simple that I'm reluctant to call it that.

Comment: "requirements doc, architecture diagrams and design docs"  I'd say all of those things are generally useless, as the requisite effort required to keep them up to date is almost never given.  Assuming anyone even writes them to begin with.  Seems like most software is designed by generating and completing tickets in a tracking system.  Good luck digging through those.

Answer (score 3):

Unit Testing is about tackling the problem of maintaining code. While there are people who say that they are faster writing code with TDD rather than without, I'm not surprised that you are able to write more new code without writing tests.

The issues that I can see with the practice of writing tests just before you change it:

**I often need to make changes in a hurry**

While you might save time overall by only writing tests when you need them, not all time is equal. Spending 2 hours writing tests to save 1 hour when I'm in crisis mode - totally worth it.

**It easier to write tests at the same time as I write the code**

To properly write unit tests you need to understand the code I'm testing. I often use unit testing as an exercise in understanding, but unit testing existing code can be time consuming because understanding existing code is time consuming. Contrast that to writing tests as you write the code and you will find it much quicker because you already understand the code - you just wrote it!

---

Michael Feathers definition of legacy code is code without tests. Regardless of whether you agree with his definition its clear that a substantial portion of the cost of modifying existing code is making sure that it still works as expected, often its not even clear what the expected behaviour is.

Writing unit tests offsets that cost by encoding an understanding of what the correct behaviour is, as well as providing an easy way for "future us" to check that behaviour is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

I could not recommend your approach.

If I use your approach it would be for example like the following(the house is the application):

1. I start building a house for my family as a bricklayer with some knowledge or as beginner.
2. I know the requirements like child rooms, guest room and start              building my "prototype" house.
3. Than a couple of times later your "prototype" house is done.
4. I start looking if the structure is stable enough manually. So I pick up a lot of weights and bring it into the different rooms in the first floor. To make sure when I sit in a room with my family the ceiling don't break. But it breaks and I start refactoring. First cleaning all the mass up. Than build it new and test it again manually until it is stable enough.
5. Than I move in with my family. All is fine.
6. A moth later my cousins and parents are coming to visit us. But before they can enter our house they need to pay an architect and civil engineer to make sure the ceiling don't break when we sit in one of the rooms in the first floor.
7. The architect and civil engineer have a lot of work because they have nothing to start with. So they need to go into my house and look how I build it.
8. And again it is not stable enough. So they have to refactor the ground of the first floor.
9. But after that everything is fine and all can safely enter my house.

So your approach costs a lot of time and a lot of knowledge before I build the house with your approach. Or it take a bunch of time!
Also it is not pretty Gentleman to let other write tests for your code when there requirements has changed.

So there is a better approach without programming a "prototype" and than start refactoring. Instead of programming a prototype" make a Design with UML of your Application as follows.

1. Create a UseCase diagram. You can use [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) to start with.
2. Than create a EPK diagram based on your UseCases to determine the behavior. (BEHAVIOR of your Application) Faster to refactor than refactor a coded prototype. Especially when you are a beginner.
3. Create a class Diagram. (STRUCTURE of your Application)
4. Determine where you could get trouble in the Implementation of the behavior.
5. Write for that a simple prototype with maybe 10 or 20 lines of code to determine how you can implement this behavior. Good for beginner. Or watch a tutorial, look into source code of other example applications out there. How they solved it.
6. Than start coding. Fist the succeed tests of your UseCase. This can be done in different ways. First create all the Structure that is needed for the test and that UseCase. When use [Enterprise Architekt](https://www.sparxsystems.de/start/startseite/) the structure can be generated for you. Based on your Diagrams. Or create the structure while wiring the Test. So no compile errors appear. Mention here is that you ONLY need to test the BEHAVIOR of your application. The UseCases you have.
7. Than Implement the behavior of your UseCase.
8. After the succeed UseCases start write Tests for the exceptions. And it feels always good when you see the green colors when your tests are valid ;)
9. And you are done.

Sure this approach needs also some Knowledge in UML but it is fast to learn.  And it is always faster to rename a Class or move arrows in a digram than do it in your IDE. But learning the use of test frameworks will be more exhausting at the beginning. Best is here to look run test of open source projects and look how they work. But when you ave a test driven application the next application will be much faster. And I think it's a good feeling to know everything works fine.

So I just down vote the approaches because they are very time consuming for beginners and not good after all. To have a clean borders between your structure and the behavior you can use the Domain driven Design and under Arrange very Domain with two Packages(one package named structure and the other named behavior). Also for your tests. 
simple example check out this [Example](https://github.com/Rocks360/oauth2-server-contract-test.git) written in java.

Answer (score 1):

> The code I'm writing works. It works because I'm testing it manually.

Did you test manually every possible branch of your conditions after little change? How long takes on feedback loop of your manual testing. How close it to feedback loop you get with automated tests.

Automated tests(doesn't matter test-first or not) makes you go fast - by providing faster feedback loop on your code.

Are you sure you will remember to test some condition manually after six month - please don't say you will document all important condition to test - because writing kind of documentation/comment is equals to writing test(executable documentation)

> - Pick a vertical slice of work
> - Develop a functioning prototype
> - Refactor until everything is nice and tidy

And again: while refactoring did you manually test all logic which get affected by refactoring? How long time takes to test on refactoring change? If refactoring breaks some code how long time takes you find a reason for breaks?

> - Sit back an appreciate the beautifully SOLID and testable code I've written.

Beautiful and clean code you enjoyed is very subjective. Your code can be clean and reasonable for you. Best method to check if your code really readable, understandable and testable is tests and code reviews made by other developers.

You found your way very productive only because you are only developer working with the code, and, I think, because you only starting working in this project(How old this project you working on?  6 - 8 month?).
You still remember everything you wrote and you can recognize a reason for possible problems. I am pretty sure you will start writing tests from beginning after 2 - 3 years of your project - because you want to be sure that you doesn't forget anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you never make mistakes you don't really need tests. Most developers do make mistakes, but if you never do, and you are confident you will never make mistakes in the future (and you are the only one on the project), there is really no reason to waste time writing tests.

But your solution is kind of halfway because you are proposing to write tests when changing code, but at the same time your method assumes that you'll never make mistakes when you decide which parts of the code to write tests for. This only works if you always understand perfectly which areas a change may affect. I think many common developers (not you of course!) have experienced to make a change, and then a test somewhere unexpected fails, because you made a mistake.

Of course good architecture, SOLID principles etc. should prevent this happening, but most developers are not perfect, and this is why tests across the system are valuable.

Comment: *Of course good architecture, SOLID principles etc. should prevent this happening* - nope. Complex systems have parts that affect other parts, that's just how it is. e.g. modifying the Antlr grammar in [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) can easily make the intended modified part work perfectly, while breaking 45 other features. Without thorough tests, there's no way to know, and you'd have to be insane to want to manually test all cases every time. If I change something in the resolver and 987 tests break, I know I did something wrong and what it affected.